# Java PrintWriter - How do you split into a number of documents depending on how many lines the user wants?

Tags: java

```
public class FileSplitter {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        // Enter the number of lines you would like in each document
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(
                "Enter the number of lines you would like in each document(please note any remainders will go into a document of their own) ");

        // variables
        int numberOfLinesPerDocument = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        int lineCounter = 0;

        int increase = 0;
        String lineBreak = String.valueOf(increase);
        File file = new File("test1.txt");

        File inputFile = getInputFileFromUser();

        try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(inputFile)) {

            try (PrintWriter thePrintWriter = new PrintWriter(file)) {
                while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
                    lineCounter++;
                    thePrintWriter.println(line);
                    if (lineCounter == numberOfLinesPerDocument) {
                        lineCounter = 0;

                        increase++;
                        thePrintWriter.close();
                        lineBreak = String.valueOf(increase);
                        file = new File("testing" + lineBreak + ".txt");
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("System Failure: ");
        }

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    private static File getInputFileFromUser() {
        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter path to input file path >>> ");
        String path = userInput.nextLine();

        File inputFile = new File(path);
        if (inputFile.exists() == false) {
            System.out.println(path + " does not exist");
            System.exit(1);
        } else if (inputFile.isFile() == false) {
            System.out.println(path + " is not a file");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        return inputFile;
    }
}
```

Please help me split this file into multiple files.  I have tried many things and none of them work.  So if i give the program 5 lines and the document has 500... that should split out 100 documents randomly.  I am only able to get one document to print with all 500 lines.  Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close already!

Note that your PrinterWriter is never being re-initialized, as you intend. That's why you only have 1 file being written.

```
try (Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(inputFile)) {
       PrintWriter thePrintWriter = new PrintWriter(file); // <--change
       while (fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
          String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
          lineCounter++;
          thePrintWriter.println(line);
          if (lineCounter == numberOfLinesPerDocument) {
                lineCounter = 0;
                increase++;
                thePrintWriter.close();
                lineBreak = String.valueOf(increase);
                file = new File("testing" + lineBreak + ".txt");
                thePrintWriter = new PrintWriter(file); // <--change
          }
       }
       thePrintWriter.close(); // <--change
} catch (IOException ex) {
    System.out.println("System Failure: ");
}
scan.close(); // <--change
```

I took the PrintWriter out of the try-with-resources style due to this error `The resource thePrintWriter of a try-with-resources statement cannot be assigned`. The rest is as you wrote it! Oh, but close your scanner. :)